# Проверка корректности слов в textarea и input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой. Я был уверен, что в 2017 году с такой проблемой не столкнусь. Ну или я плохо гуглил.

Заранее скажу что SaaS решения, API и подобное очень нежелательны в данной реализации.

Вот в чем суть.

Есть поля в формах, которые как-то нужно проверить - spell checking. Речь идет об простом - английском языке. Работать это должно следующим образом: написал текст, нажал на кнопку, получил результат ("плохие" слова нужно как-то получить).

Я гуглил не один день. Все что я смог найти - это реализации, в целом очень похожи друг на друга. Хотя, я бы даже назвал их идентичными. Суть у них заключалась в том, что нужно ставить какие-то библиотеки для PHP на сервер (а мне PHP на фиг не сдался сейчас)...

А мне нужно под Ruby. Под Rails. И все что я смог найти из более-менее актуального - это gem'ы, которые основаны на API. Но, как я писал в самом начале - это крайняя мера. И очень желательно обойтись без этого.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое-нибудь решение проблемы. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А при чём тут жуквери?

Comment: Под Linux есть некоторый ассортимент проверяльщиков орфографии с CLI или даже в формате библиотек. Логичный шаг -- проверить для каждого, нет ли биндингов на них для Ruby.